# WMC HTPC breaks down over time, reformat the disk and joy... for awhile

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-media-center, htpc

Trying to diagnose whats going on with my HTPC. It will run great for awhile and then over the course of a month it begins to bog down and eventually become unusable at which point I reinstall the OS and it runs great then it starts all over again. I thought that there might be an issue with the motherboard but the fact that I can reinstall the OS and have it all joyful again makes me think different.  Possibly a bad or failing HDD?

**Issues:**

1. Windows takes a long time to bootup.
2. Computer locks up and has to be hard bounced.
3. Unresponsive at times and slow in general.

Other issues have to do with WMC:

1. Playback of WMC recorded tv will work for a few minutes then it will stop with the error: "Files needed to display video are not installed or are not working correctly."
2. sometimes wont play live tv
3. audio goes out, i have to disable then re-enable the default audio device to get it back to work.

**I have:**

- updated the BIOS,

  ensured all the drivers are up to date

  firmware is current on the HDHomerun Prime.

**Specs:**

- Windows 7 Ultimate
- GIGABYTE GA-MA78GM-US2H AM2+/AM2 AMD 780G HDMI Micro ATX AMD Motherboard
- AMD Athlon 64 X2 5600 Brisbane 2.9GHz Socket AM2 65W Dual-Core Processor
- 450W PSU
- CORSAIR XMS2 4GB (2 x 2GB) DDR2 800 (PC2 6400) Dual Channel
- ATI Radeon HD 5450
- HD Homerun prime tuner

Any insight would be appreciated.

[crysalDiskInfo images on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5OUy.jpg)

Comment: provide pictures of http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html Here we can see if the HDD is bad.

Comment: updated post with link to crystalDiskInfo screenshots.  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected, your Harddrives dies. Look at the yellow entries for "Uncorrectable sector count", "Current pending sector count" and "Reallocated sector count". Backup all data as soon as possible and buy new drives.

Answer (score -1):

Could be that some program you run is in a crashed state, building up cache or some sort of memory leak.

What I do is have my HTPC reboot automatically by setting the BIOS "Power settings".
Hit "Delete" when you reboot."